# Copy and paste a range of cell values into another sheet with VBA and using Offset

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I want to copy and paste values from one sheet to another via button assigned to a macro. And every time I hit the button the pasted values should skip some rows so it doesn't paste on the previous values. Below is my code so far, the problem is that the loop never stops. There is probably a better way? maybe a loop isn't the way to do it?

Please post the answer in code if you know, or give me some tips. I would really appreciate it.

```
Sub Savestrategy()

Dim Bookmark As Integer
Dim positioner As Integer

For Each cell In Range("A2:L20")

    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Bookmark").Copy

    Worksheets("Bookmarks").Range("A2").Offset(positioner, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Worksheets("Bookmarks").Range("A2").Offset(positioner, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    positioner = positioner + 20

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I just ran your code for `A2:B20` and it worked fine (the loop ended). is "Bookmark" a named range in your sheet? Your code will paste the same value( in `Range("Bookmark")`) every 20th line from A2 in the Bookmarks sheet. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick reply. No, I want it paste the values one time not like 80 times. And then the next time I hit the button I want it to paste the values again but 20 rows down the previous paste. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I believe you can use an IsEmpty and if statement maybe? but not sure how to do it. Maybe you know?

Comment: And yes "bookmark" is a named range in my sheet

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping? You are not even using the range to loop.

Not tested but you can see where i am going with it. If i knew the range of "Bookmark."  I could help you further.

```
Worksheets("Bookmarks").Range("A2:L20").Offset(20, 0).value = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range(Bookmark).value
```

Comment: You do not but quotations around ranges. It will just assume that it is a name not a range.

Comment: I found the solution now, I shouldn't even loop as you said. Since I just want to copy and paste values from the same range once, but then the next time I paste the values I want it to go down 20 rows.